# Sonar Treemap with custom levels

Tags: sonarqube

My project has directory structure like below

```
com/zombie/user/login/login.java 
com/zombie/user/login/register.java
com/zombie/user/login/forgotPassword.java
com/zombie/user/logoff/logoff.java
com/zombie/account/myaccount/addAddress.java
com/zombie/account/myaccount/deleteAddress.java
```

Default Sonar Treemap is always at the package level under the project.
    Like,

```
   Project->com.zombie.user.login->Classes
   Project->com.zombie.user.logoff->Classes
   Project->com.zombie.account.myaccount->Classes
```

But I want the treemap like the below.

```
   Project->User->com.zombie.user.login->Classes
   Project->Account->com.zombie.account.myaccount->Classes
```

How do I get this done?
I am new to Sonar and any small help will be much appreciated!!